# How to fix this code for N/3 Repeat Number

Tags: java

I am doing this problem from the interview bit.

You’re given a read-only array of n integers. Find out if any integer
 occurs more than n/3 times in the array in linear time and constant
 additional space.

If so, return the integer. If not, return -1.

If there are multiple solutions, return any one.

> Example :
>
> - Input : [1 2 3 1 1]
> - Output : 1
>
>   1 occurs 3 times which is more than 5/3 times.

Here is my code its giving wrong answer can anybody correct where am I wrong.

```
public class Solution {
    // DO NOT MODIFY THE LIST
    public int repeatedNumber(final List<Integer> a) {
        int size =a.size();
        double c=size/3;
        int num=0;
        int n=0,m=1,l=size-1;
        double count=1;
        while(l>m && size>=3){
            if(a.get(n)==a.get(m) && a.get(n)!=a.get(l)){
                num=a.get(n);
                l--;
                count=count+1;
            }else if(a.get(n)==a.get(l) && a.get(n)!=a.get(m)){
                num=a.get(n);
                l--;
                count+=1;
            }else if(a.get(m)==a.get(l) && a.get(n)!=a.get(m)){
                num=a.get(m);
                l--;
                count+=1;
            }else if(a.get(n)==a.get(m)&& a.get(n)==a.get(l)){
                num=a.get(n);
                l--;
                if(count>0){
                    count+=1;
                }else{
                    count+=2;
                }
            }else{
                n++;
                m++;
                l--;
            }
        }
        if(count>1&& count>c){
            return num;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

A : [ 1000441, 1000441, 1000994 ]

Your function returned the following :

-1
```

The expected returned value :

Any number that appears more than n/3 times

This is the output

Comment: Can you explain how your code is (supposed to) work?

Comment: Well, _technically_, if all the numbers are `Integer`, you could use an array of size `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to count the individual numbers, which would totally satisfy the "constant additional space" constraint. :-P

Comment: We need to solve this question for O(n) Complexity. So i used three variables n,m and l. Now in the while loop. It checks the condition. For the given test case, as you can see in while loop first if condition is statisfied but still  i am getting wrong answer. Please check that.

Comment: Your comment in no way explains how the algorithm is supposed to work. (It might work for the test case, but what about the general case?) What are those three variables supposed to represent, and what does the condition signify?

Comment: I don't understand how your algorithm is supposed to work. To me, it seems you are comparing random Integer instances to each other. Not sure how you are going to find integers that occur most repeatedly and more than n/3 times. Anyway - your if statement never evaluates to true as you are comparing Integer instances with the equals operator. Found using the debugger. Typically, the integer references will not point to the the same instance, even if they have the same value. So you you should compare using `equals()` method.

Comment: Okay, i got the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to achieve it with `linear` complexity, you can use `HashMap` for this purpose, and maintain a maxCount, and if it's greater than `n/3` you can return `true`.
Code:

```
public boolean checkCount(int[] array, int n) {
    int maxCount = 0;
    Map<Integer,Integer> numberCountMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        int number = array[i];
        int count = numberCountMap.getOrDefault(number,0);
        numberCountMap.put(number, ++count);
        if(count > maxCount){
            maxCount = count;
        }
    }
    if(maxCount >= n/3){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

In the `HashMap` the key is the `number` in array and its value is `its total count`. So initially it will check whether it exists in `map` or not and then `increments` its value. also that value is compared with `maxCount`. So in the end if `maxCount` is greater or equals to `n/3` its a `true` else `false`.

> So for input array: [1,2,1,4,6,1,1] it gives output: true

Comment: Of course, this takes a very liberal stance on the "constand additional space" constraint... Also, it does not return the number with that count. Instead, you should check the count each time you increment it and then just return that number if `>n/3`

Comment: Yes i think so this is a better approach to solve this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems with your code.

The main problem you're having right now is that you compare Integer objects with `==`.
This will check to see if the references are the same. Which they appear not to be.
It doesn't matter if the value is the same, as it's still two different Integer objects (probably the 'fault' of the List, as you can technically create two different Integer objects that will evaluate to true using the `==` operator).

The easiest way to do this correctly is to either use:

```
a.intValue() == b.intValue()
```

or

```
a.equals(b)
```

The latter being a bit less efficient, but less code to write.

The other thing I'd like to mention is

```
double c=size/3;
```

`size` is an int, so is `3`. So even if you have a `size` of `5`, `c` will be `1.0`.

That's because the first thing that happens will be the calculation of `5/3` (which - since they are both ints) will be `1`. Then you assign that `1` to a double variable, making it `1.0`.
You will need to cast one of those two values to double if you want to actually get the correct result (unless you don't need it in which case: why use double at all?)

One last thing:
Your code as it is right now will not work for more complicated examples.
But that's an entirely different problem and would lead into the "doing your homework for you" problem, so I won't go into that right now. Just ask a new question once you get stuck somewhere else.