# N/3 Repeat Number

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, array-algorithms

Problem is to Find out if any integer occurs more than n/3 times in the array.
The solution is based on Moore's Voting Algorithm (if we cancel out each occurrence of an element e with all the other elements that are different from e then e will exist till end if it is a majority element.)

```
    findCandidate(a[], size)
            1.  Initialize index and count of majority element
                 maj_index = 0, count = 1
            2.  Loop for i = 1 to size – 1
                 (a) If a[maj_index] == a[i]
                          count++
                 (b) Else
                          count--;
                 (c) If count == 0
                          maj_index = i;
                          count = 1
            3.  Return a[maj_index]
```

Now We just need to check if count of the candidate element is greater than n/2.

In case of finding majority element ,this way to find candidate for majority element is understood i.e number which atleast repeats more than other elements even by one are candidates but its application in this problem is not clear.

It is written that you have 3 distinct element from the array, if you remove them from the array, your answer does not change and 2 elements with their counts are maintained.

In majority case ,we maintain one which is candidate for majority but why here two are maintained regardless of required number of times changes .
Example: For n =3/4/5 its more than 1 times,for n=6/7/8 its more than 2 times etc.Pseudo code is as follows:

```
        When we encounter a new element, there are 3 cases possible :

              1)We don’t have 2 elements yet. So add this to the list with count as 1.

              2)This element is different from the existing 2 elements. As we said before, we 
                have 3 distinct numbers now. Removing them does not change the answer. So 
                decrements 1 from count of 2 existing elements. If their count falls to 0, 
                obviously its not a part of 2 elements anymore.

              3)The new element is same as one of the 2 elements. Increment the count of that 
                element.
```

Code is as follows :

```
              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 

                      // if this element is previously seen,  
                      // increment count1. 
                       if (first == arr[i]) 
                           count1++; 

                     // if this element is previously seen,  
                     // increment count2. 
                       else if (second == arr[i]) 
                           count2++; 

                       else if (count1 == 0) { 
                           count1++; 
                           first = arr[i]; 
                       } 

                       else if (count2 == 0) { 
                            count2++; 
                            second = arr[i]; 
                        } 

                       // if current element is different from 
                       // both the previously seen variables,  
                       // decrement both the counts. 
                        else { 
                             count1--; 
                             count2--; 
                       } 
                } 

                count1 = 0; 
                count2 = 0; 

               // Again traverse the array and find the 
               // actual counts. 
              for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { 
                       if (arr[i] == first) 
                              count1++; 

                        else if (arr[i] == second) 
                               count2++; 
} 

                     if (count1 > n / 3) 
                            return first; 

                    if (count2 > n / 3) 
                            return second; 



         Consequently, the answer will be one of the 2 elements left behind. If they are 
         not the answer, then there is no element with count > N / 3
```

Why is candidates being considered is two and eligibility criteria?

Comment: As this seems to be a question more about the algorithm and not about a specific implementation I removed the `c++` tag and added the `language-agnostic` tag.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56540719/how-to-fix-this-code-for-n-3-repeat-number